# Search in a file with good performance

Tags: java, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a search in a 200,000 text files whose size may vary from 50kb to 5 mb which comes to a total of 1.7GB. I'm planning to develop a search engine(Just a sample one). 
The process is:

```
1) Extract words from each file and store them in a separate file(40,000,000 words)
2) Search each word in each file ( 40,000,000(words) X 200,000(Files) = 8 X 10^12 searches)
3) Generate boolean Index(650Mb).
```

So, most of the operation involved here will be searching in document(s) or file(s). In which 2nd step takes a lot of time.(4+ hours)

This is the program I've written for searching a word in JAVA.

```
count = 0;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('fileName.txt'));
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
if( text.indexOf(searchString) != -1 )
{
    if( text.equals(searchString))
    {
        System.out.print('Word Found in line number '+count);
        break;
    }
}
count++;
}
```

Program in PYTHON:

```
count = 0
file = open(filePath)
with file as f :
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        if(line.index(searchWord))
            print("Word found in line number"+count)
```

Output is perfect, but it takes lot of time. Language is not a considering criteria for me. I'm looking for a better performance. Is there any way that I can make it out of it. As most of it is searching process, is there any perfect way coz it is searching large pieces of small chunks.

(My PC Config: 8GB RAM, i7 4th Generation)

Comment: So you're trying to implement `grep` in Java?

Comment: Why are you working in both Java and Python? Which language do you want a solution for?

Comment: And do you need to write a program or can you just look for a tool to do this?

Comment: It shouldn't take anywhere near that long.  You can readline() at a rate of close to 100 MB/s and I wouldn't expect this to take more than a minute.

Comment: Do you have some antivirus programm running?

Comment: This is the actual concept behind

Answer (score 3):

You can split your file into multiple chunks & then Process those chunks parallely using different Threads. (Similar to Map Reduce)

Example : Split file in chunks of 100MB each (say there are 17 chunks)

Now you can pass these chunks to individual threads and then search for the text.

```
public class SearchText
{

  public void processFile()
  {
    List<Chunks> totalChunks = splitFile(); 
    // you have to implement splitFile() function to split file in chunks

    for(Chunks chunk : totakChunks)
    {
       // Create a new Thread and process the chunks
       new Thread(new ChunkProcessor(chunk)).start();
    }
  }
}

public class ChunkProcessor implements Runnable
{

   private Chunk mychunk ;
   public ChunkProcessor(Chunk chunk)
   {
     myChunk = chunk;
   }


   public void run()
   {
      // search for text in this chunk
   } 
}
```

Comment: (Not in Python, though...)

Comment: @Wooble, probably would be good to clarify you could do it in Python, it just wouldn't help any

Comment: Splitting the file is typically done sequentially and usually takes as long as just reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Running one of the cheapest laptop I could buy which runs Windows 7.

```
public class SearchTestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("deleteme.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numbers = 42 * 1000 * 1000;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Writing " + file);
        // average line length ~36 bytes.
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
            pw.println(rand.nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE); // positive only
            pw.println(rand.nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE); // positive only
        }
        pw.close();
        long mid = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Reading " + file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String searchTerm = "31415926";
        for (String line; ((line = br.readLine())) != null; )
            if (line.contains(searchTerm))
                System.out.println("found " + searchTerm + " in " + line);
        br.close();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Writing took %.1f seconds, reading took %.1f seconds for a %,d MB file%n",
                (mid - start) / 1e3, (end - mid) / 1e3, file.length() / 1000000);
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Writing deleteme.txt
Reading deleteme.txt
found 31415926 in 6728531415926595287
found 31415926 in 8919165331415926916
... some deleted ...
found 31415926 in 2826331415926854237
found 31415926 in 5676780473141592623
Writing took 35.5 seconds, reading took 55.1 seconds for a 1,753 MB file
```

I would be very surprised if reading and search the text alone takes much more than a minute.  If it takes much longer, it is doing something you are not telling us.

Comment: Yeah.. This is not the whole Idea of the program, i have several other tasks to perform, and searching in different files the basic Idea. The main purpose is to implement boolean Indexes and develop a search engine

Comment: @user1919035 and if you are taking 10 minute in total, I suspect this extra stuff is the other 9 minutes. i.e. reading/searching is just 10% of your problem.

Comment: @user1919035 I suggest you use a CPU/Memory profiler to see what it is doing most of the time.  Without measurement I find I am just guessing ;)

Comment: Nope.. I've to search many files like that.. 200,000 files(1.7 GB), and I've to search each file for 42 million unique words. I guess I need to go one file and one word at a time. I thought that searching might be going late. So, do you have any idea to perform this type of search?

Comment: @user1919035 My guess is you have a HDD.  When you have lots of files it takes time to read each one.  About 10 ms for a HDD, and about 0.1 for an SSD. To read 200K files from disk can take 2000 seconds or a little over 35 minutes.  Fortunately many of your files will be cache as it tends to read multiple files at once.  In short, don't have so many files or don't use a HDD, or defragment (put them all together on the disk ;) them if you can.

Comment: Yeah.. I"m using HDD. I can use SSD instead. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build an Index using [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure first and then implement search on it.